# How to change class name using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, devexpress

I'm trying to change an ASPxClientLabel's classname from javascript.  How to do this?

I tried this:

This label is inside of repeater control:

```
<dx:ASPxLabel ID="labelShortName" runat="server" CssClass="shortNameItemLink"
ClientSideEvents-Click="function(s, e){ ShortName_Clicked(s, e); }"
Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ShortName")%>'>  
</dx:ASPxLabel>
```

This label starts out as "clicked"

```
<dx:ASPxLabel ID="labelShowAll" runat="server" 
ClientSideEvents-Click="function(s, e){ ShortName_Clicked(s, e); }" Text="Show All" 
CssClass="shortNameItemLinkClicked"></dx:ASPxLabel>
```

[JS]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShortName_Clicked(s, e) {
        var selectedText = s.GetText();
        var items = $('.shortNameItemLinkClicked');
        items.removeClass();
        items.addClass('shortNameItemLink');
        $(s).className = "shortNameItemLinkClicked";
 }
</script>
```

I get "undefined" error.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can't rename the class...either you can add or remove existing one then add required one

Comment: From your code i found that "ShortName_Clicked" function missing closing }.Are you forgot to paste here?.If you miss it, This will be a issue.

Comment: @sathishkumar - thank you.  I updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to put my own answer, but none of the others seemed to work.

I fixed it like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShortName_Clicked(s, e) {
        var selectedText = s.GetText();
        $('.shortNameItemLinkClicked')
        .removeClass()
        .addClass('shortNameItemLink');

        $('#' + s.name)
        .removeClass("shortNameItemLink")
        .addClass("shortNameItemLinkClicked"); 
    }
</script>
```

from devexpress documentation: [ASPxClientLabel](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientLabelMembersTopicAll)

thanks @ShankarSangoli for method chaining refactorage.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
function ShortName_Clicked(s, e) {
        var selectedText = s.GetText();
        $('.shortNameItemLinkClicked')
        .removeClass()
        .addClass('shortNameItemLink');
        $(s).attr('class', 'shortNameItemLinkClicked');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
 $(s).attr("class","shortNameItemLinkClicked");
```

?

Comment: I tried now, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working.  When it is working (I used a regular span element) a little > arrow shows up next to the item I clicked.  I don't get error, but I also don't get an arrow.  I need to look into it more, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing your add / remove backwards.  Try the following

```
function ShortName_Clicked(s, e) {
  $('.shortNameItemLink').removeClass().addClass('shortNameItemLinkClicked');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The class names don't quite match up in your HTML and jQuery. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShortName_Clicked(s, e) {
        var selectedText = s.GetText();

        $('.shortNameItemLink').removeClass().addClass('shortNameItemLinkClicked');
    }
</script>
```

I also added the closing brace as it was missing from your example - I'm not sure if this was just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(s).className = "shortNameItemLinkClicked";
```

should be
`$(s).get(0).className = "shortNameItemLinkClicked"`;

or if you know the existing className

```
$(s).removeClass("shortNameItemLink").addClass("shortNameItemLinkClicked");
```